# Identify and list all ERC-721 and ERC-1155 token using a node

Tags: erc-721, erc-1155, archive-node

I want to get a list of all ERC-721 and ERC-1155 based contracts. How can I do this using an Ethereum node? Do I need a full node to achieve this?

Google BigQuery only supports ERC-721 tokens right now.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, other question is asking for NFTs. This is asking for all NFT contracts. They are different things and the data can be collected differently. MODS: please reopen

Comment: The linked duplicates explains exactly what is asked here. And even if not, this question needs clarity. What is BigQuery doing here ? What have you tried ? What does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

I did this using Graph protocol. There is already an existing subgraph available that does this -- https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/amxx/eip721-subgraph.